# How to create multiple rows based on list values stores in column in dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

For example I have two rows:

```
ID,dep_id
EMP1,1,2,3
EMP2,4,5,6
```

I want the output as :

```
ID,dep_id
EMP1,1
EMP1,2
EMP1,3
EMP2,4
EMP2,5
EMP2,6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas` for this:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data = '''ID,dep_id
EMP1,"1,2,3"
EMP2,"4,5,6"'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data)) # insert your csv here
df['dep_id'] = ('['+df['dep_id']+ ']').apply(pd.eval) # turn string to list
df.explode('dep_id')df.explode('dep_id').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

|  | ID | dep_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | EMP1 | 1 |
| 1 | EMP1 | 2 |
| 2 | EMP1 | 3 |
| 3 | EMP2 | 4 |
| 4 | EMP2 | 5 |
| 5 | EMP2 | 6 |

Comment: data = '''ID,dep_id
EMP1,"1,2,3"
EMP2,"4,5,6"'''

The data is already stored in a df 

Hence this is not working df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data)) # insert your csv here

Comment: then .... skip that line?

Comment: Getting error : TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: what if we take the table like : 
```ID,dep_id
EMP1,1,2,3
EMP2,4,5,6
```

Comment: I can't guess the dtype of your columns. Was assuming it was a string. If it is a list of ints you can just do `df.explode('dep_id')df.explode('dep_id')`